# What are the interrupt levels for the Receiver Control Register

Tags: assembly, mips, interrupt-handling

I am trying to create a hardware interrupt handler that processes keyboard input. The problem is my handler is only supposed to continue if the Receiver Control Register has a value of 1. Currently, my code is producing a value of 3, so my handler simply exits because I ONLY want to handle hardware interrupts. I cannot find anywhere online that describes what a level 3 interrupt is and how I can fix my code so it gives a level 1 interrupt.

Can someone please tell me what level 3 is or at least point me to a resource? Thanks

To add to this. I am also getting 256 as the value for my cause register. I think all the codes are in hex, therefore that would be a code 4. Which I can see is a load from illegal address. This doesn't make sense because the interrupt handler isn't even called until i hit a key on the keyboard. Heres the code:

```
.data 0xffff0000 
RecvCtrlReg: .word 0

.ktext  0x80000180

    #move   $k1, $at

    #la $k0, frogger    # save the address to frogger function for long call

    mfc0    $k1, $13
    beq $k1, 0, keyboard    # If cause register is not zero, exit

    li  $v0, 10     # Do nothing and exit
    syscall

    keyboard:           # else check interupt level

    lw  $t7, RecvCtrlReg    
    beq $t7, 1, continue    # if the Reciever Control Reg is 1, its a hardware interrupt, so continue

    li  $v0, 10     # else do nothing and exit
    syscall
    continue:

    jalr    $k0     # long call frogger function

    mtc0    $0, $13     # set cause register to 0

    mfc0    $k0, $12        # Fix status register
    andi    $k0, 0xfffd # clear EXL bit
    ori $k0, 0x1        # Enable interrupts
    mtc0    $k0, $12        # Store value back into status register

    #move   $at, $k1

    eret
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not just `Cause` register interrupt bit field's alone sufficient and takes the request. Normally the interrupt field of the Cause register is bit wise ANDed with the interrupt field of `Status` register also. The resultant bits are ORed together and the value is ANDed with the IE(master enable for interrupts) bit of `Status` register will cause an interrupt.